# Firebase Database permission denied error when using addValueEventListener()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to get data and load it into a fragment. The fragment contains a list where I want to add date using an adapter. The adapter takes in 3 arraylists as input to create a customized list.

Here is the `AttendanceFragment`:

```
public class AttendanceFragment extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference reference, attendance, classid, divisionid, studentid, dates;
    private Button attbutton;
    private ListView list;
    private View mainview;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>(),
            state = new ArrayList<String>(),
            teacher = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendence,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        mainview = this.getView();
        activity = this.getActivity();
        attbutton = mainview.findViewById(R.id.att_per);
        list = mainview.findViewById(R.id.att_main_list);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        attendance = reference.child(KeyStrings.attendance);
        classid = attendance.child(KeyStrings.class1);
        divisionid = classid.child(KeyStrings.division1);
        studentid = divisionid.child(KeyStrings.student1);
        dates = studentid.child("2018-07-06");
        attbutton.setText(dates.getKey());

        studentid.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Does it work?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for(DataSnapshot d1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    date.add(d1.getKey());
                    state.add(d1.child(KeyStrings.att_status).getValue().toString());
                    teacher.add(d1.child(KeyStrings.att_created_by).getValue().toString());
                }

                listAdapter = new AttendanceAdapter(activity, date, state, teacher);
                list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

The code manages to set the attbutton with the text in the 'dates' key stored in Firebase. Thus, an indication that there is no connection or permission problem. But no code of the `addValueEventListener` works.

It gives the following error:

> Listen at /Attendance/1/A/1 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

This happens only for the `addValueEventListener` and nothing is added to the arraylists. The event is actually not even triggered, since neither the toast message is displayed.

Here is the code for the `AttendanceAdapter`:

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private ArrayList<String> date;
    private ArrayList<String> state;
    private ArrayList<String> teacher;
    private Activity context;

    public AttendanceAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String>date, ArrayList<String>state, ArrayList<String>teacher) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_attendence, date);
        this.date=date;
        this.state=state;
        this.teacher=teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listviewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendence,null,true);
        TextView dateview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.att_list_date);
        TextView stateview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.att_list_stat);
        TextView teacherview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.att_list_teacher);

        dateview.setText(date.get(position));
        stateview.setText(state.get(position));
        teacherview.setText(teacher.get(position));
        return listviewItem;
    }
}
```

EDIT 1

As I said earlier, there is probably no permission or authentication problem at Firebase. But here are the rules:

{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: Please include your datastructure and security rules in your question.

Comment: Can you share your Firebase Database security rules with us? You can access the rules from the [Rules tab on the Database section of the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/rules).